# Matplotlib Frame Invisible

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

The frame of my axis inside my figure are invisible. I tried ax.spines.set_visible(True), ax.axis("on"), etc. but nothing seems to work. Below you can find the code for the specific plot I am trying to draw and the settings I use at the beginning. Anyone know how to make the frame around the axis visible? I checked the solutions that are already on stackoverflow but they didn't work for me either. Thanks.

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    mpl.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    plt.style.use(['seaborn-white','seaborn-paper'])
    import seaborn as sns
    sns.set(font='serif')

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)

    ax1.set_facecolor("white")
    ax1.axhline(19, color='r', label='$T_{lim}$')
    ax1.axhline(23, color='r')
    ax1.plot(Tair, color='b', linewidth=1, label='$T_{air}$')
    ax1.plot(Tout, color='m', linewidth=1, label='$T_{out}$')
    ax1.set_ylabel('T [°C]', fontsize=15)
    ax1.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
    ax1.set_xlim([0, 1440 * (day + 1)])
    ax1.set_xlabel('Time [quarters]', fontsize=15)

    ax2.set_facecolor("white")
    ax2.plot(u_phys, color='b', linewidth=1, label='$u$')
    ax3 = ax2.twinx()
    ax3.plot(price, color='g', linewidth=1, label='$p$')
    ax3.grid(b=False)
    ax3.set_ylabel('Price [€c / kWh]', fontsize=15, color='g')
    ax3.tick_params('y', colors='g')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Time [quarters]', fontsize=15)
    ax2.set_ylabel('Power [kW]', fontsize=15, color='b')
    ax2.tick_params('y', colors='b')
    ax2.set_xlim([0, 1440 * (day + 1)])
    ax2.set_ylim(0, 3.2)
    ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(1440 * (day + 1))[::1440])
    ax2.set_xticklabels(np.arange(day + 1))
    ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(self.n_actions + 1))
    ax2.set_yticklabels(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
    ax2.xaxis.set_visible(True)
    ax1.xaxis.set_visible(True)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.09, wspace=0, hspace=0.26, right=0.88, bottom=0.09, top=0.97)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing a lot of styles here. It would be best to decide for either seaborn style or matplotlib style and only use one of them to define the style. 
Since it seems you don't actually need seaborn here, you may leave it out completely.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use(['seaborn-white','seaborn-paper'])
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
```

[image]